# Is there a good solution to the CDATA issues

Tags: spring-boot, jax-ws, spring-ws

I've been searching now for weeks to find a good solution for handling CDATA in a SOAP based Web Service and Web Service client.   I've scoured the internet for examples and solutions, but nothing seems to work.  I've found this has been a problem for several years based on posts here and elsewhere on the web and has yet to be solved with a simple implementation.  I have used MOXy and I have a JAX-WS Client running in a Weblogic service that is working with it.  Though it’s simple it only works under WebLogic and I can’t run it as standalone java app.   Now I’m trying to use Spring Boot and Spring WS to port an existing Web Service that uses CDATA both in it’s Service and as an outgoing Client call to another service.   The port is from AXIS 1 which supported CDATA, which is old and I’d hoped the CDATA issue was solved by now with Spring Web Services.   Though I found the following Issue requesting a work around for support for it here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21921

I’ve tried all the hacks like adding an Interceptor to add a CDATASection, but in the Xerces transform when it creates the SAAJ SOAP message in the end it’s treated as regular text still.   For the Client code I tried pulling in MOXy like I did under WebLogic and the MOXy plugin jars and tracing it through the debugger it does set the Elements Property to CDATA using the @XMLCDATA annotation, but the data is not wrapped in CDATA and is still escaped in the end.

I know the Java frameworks support it, just based on debugging I can see there is tons of code in the libraries to handle CDATA, but what I can’t find is a working example without requiring a specific Containers implementation like Weblogic and MOXy.

Has anyone solved this problem that could share how they have CDATA working in either a JAX-WS or a Spring WS or both?   I know this is a rather general question and I didn't provide any solid examples of all the things I've tried, but what I'm looking for is if anyone out there has gotten this to work lately in Spring Boot/WS's and or JAX-WS.  In some of the issues I found it appeared as if they may have gotten past this issue some years ago, but these same solutions either don't now or I'm not getting the full set of pieces to the puzzle.

thanks,
Smitty

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. It also helps you solving the question yourself.